# Equation of motion - gravity + force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Hi I'm looking to see if its possible to come up with an equation of motion that can calculate the position of an object through time when this object is under the influence of gravity as well as another constant force towards a constant point in 3D space. It should take into account the initial velocity of the object as well and even reasonable approximations would do but is it possible?

Comment: By influence of gravity, do you mean the approximately uniform field near the Earth's surface or the full fledged inverse square central force?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus no the uniform field would do and I'm ok with just a, decent, approximation

Answer (score 1):

There is no general closed form solution for an object in orbit with a perturbation.  If there's just a single gravitational body, then there are closed form solutions, the [Keplerian orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit).  Adding in another force is tricky and is usually handled numerically (approximating the answer via a computer).

If your other force is relatively small compared to the effects of gravity, you may be able to solve for the orbit numerically using orbital [perturbation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_(astronomy)) techniques.  Astronomers use them to correct their predictions of objects for many effects, such as solar pressure or the effect of other gravitational bodies.  These are numeric techniques which take advantage of the fact that the orbit is *almost* defined by a [central-force problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem) to come up with accurate estimates faster than more general approaches.

If your other force is much larger than the effect of gravity, you may be able to do the opposite approach: solve the trajectory under the effect of your other force and then perturb it by gravity.

In the general case, you can use differential equations to get an answer for any trajectory, even complicated ones such as the path [Voyager 2](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4140) took through the solar system.  If you are familiar with calculus, you know that acceleration is the *derivative* of velocity and velocity is the *derivative* of position.  Differential equations lets us describe the forces on an object and then use that to solve for the trajectory.  There may not be a closed form solution available, but there are plenty of simple numeric methods for doing this, such as the venerable [RK4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is absolutely possible to do a complete analysis of the particle if we know the initial conditions.

let the particle of mass $m$ be at $(x, y, z)$ with initial velocity $\vec{v} = v_{x} \hat{i} + v_{y}\hat{j} + v_{z} \hat{k}$ with gravity $-g \hat{j}$. The external force acting on the body is $\vec{F} = F_{x}\hat{i} + F_{y}\hat{j}+F_{z}\hat{k}$.

Since $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$, $\vec{a} = a_{x}\hat{i}+a_{y}\hat{j}+a_{z}\hat{k} = \frac{F_{x}}{m}\hat{i}+\frac{F_{y}}{m}\hat{j}+\frac{F_{k}}{m}\hat{k}$.

Now, the position of the particle w.r.t time would be $\left( \left( x + v_{x}t + \frac{a_{x}}{2}t^2 \right), \left( y + v_{y}t + \frac{a_{y} - g}{2}t^2 \right), \left( z + v_{z}t + \frac{a_{z}}{2}t^2 \right) \right) = \left( \left( x + v_{x}t + \frac{F_{x}}{2m}t^2 \right), \left( y + v_{y}t + \frac{\left( \frac{F_{y}}{m} - g \right)}{2}t^2 \right), \left( z + v_{z}t + \frac{F_{z}}{2m}t^2 \right) \right)$

Comment: This would be mostly true on the Earth, but this question was tagged [orbital-mechanics] which means that the assumption that gravity is in the negative z direction does not hold.  I also say "mostly" because you're missing some 1/2's and some squares on the acceleration terms

Comment: @CortAmmon. Sorry abt that. I am clueless on what was going on in my mind when I typed this to make such an elementary mistake.